# if-else statement not running elif- or else- clauses

Tags: python, if-statement

I am using Python in an attempt to create an Area Calculator (similar to the one from Code Academy). Only my else statement seems to be running:

```
print("Area Calculator.")
print ("Select Shape:")
print ("Circle or Triangle? ")

answer = input()

if answer == "Circle" or "C" or "c" or "circle":
    radius = float(input("Input Radius: "))
    area_c = (3.12159 * radius) * 2
    print (area_c)

elif answer == "Triangle" or "T" or "t" or "triangle":
    base = float(input("Input Base: "))
    height = float(input("Input Height: "))
    area_t = (.5 * base) * height
    print (area_t)

else:
    print ("error")
```

I edit texts using PyCharm and no syntax errors or errors of any other kind return. Regardless of what I respond into the answer input (whether they are integers or syntax) the code always displays `line 8 [radius = float(input("Input Radius: "))]`

I am sorry if this turns out to be an easy fix. I am just getting started with Python and have tried a variety of indentation and syntactical variations to no avail.

Comment: `if answer == "Circle" or answer == "C" or answer == "c" or answer =="circle":`, make the same changes to your elif statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the `==` operator incorrectly. You have to use it this way:

```
if answer == "Circle" or answer == "C" or answer == "c" or answer == "circle":
```

An easier way to do this will be to using check whether your string matches any of the items in a tuple or list. So your code will need to be modified like this:

```
print("Area Calculator.")
print ("Select Shape:")
print ("Circle or Triangle? ")

answer = input()

if answer in ("Circle", "C", "c", "circle"):
    radius = float(input("Input Radius: "))
    area_c = (3.12159 * radius) * 2
    print (area_c)

elif answer in ("Triangle", "T", "t", "triangle"):
    base = float(input("Input Base: "))
    height = float(input("Input Height: "))
    area_t = (.5 * base) * height
    print (area_t)

else:
    print ("error")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Rastogi! I have implimented the suggested modifications and my code now runs exactly how I had intended it to run!

Comment: @JosephTadros Glad it worked! Remember to "accept" whichever answer was the most helpful to you. Doesn't have to be mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print("Area Calculator.")
print ("Select Shape:")
print ("Circle or Triangle? ")

answer = input()

if answer.lower() in {"circle","c"}:
    radius = float(input("Input Radius: "))
    area_c = (3.12159 * radius) * 2
    print (area_c)

elif answer.lower() in {"triangle","t"}:
    base = float(input("Input Base: "))
    height = float(input("Input Height: "))
    area_t = (.5 * base) * height
    print (area_t)

else:
    print ("error")
```

The changes are the lines with `or`, use `in` instead so checks by the set

That's what's different.

Note use `lower` for simplifying the length

Note use `set` for speed, (it's faster)

Comment: Thank you U9-Forwad for helping me with this code. I do have one question if you don't mind, there is one thing I don't understand. What do you mean by "Note use set for speed, (it's faster)"? I know that by sets you mean the swigly lines as opposed to parentheses but what is the utility in using sets as opposed to just parentheses? I have searched the information on the Python website and another coding site but I still don't understand what they mean. Thank you again very much for assisting me!

Comment: @JosephTadros Oh remember, i looked the duplicate question's accepted answer, it says "using a set to take advantage of the constant-cost membership test (in takes a fixed amount of time whatever the left-hand operand is)."

Answer (score -2):

```
if answer == "Circle" or answer == "C" or answer == "c" or answer == "circle":
```

Comment: You need explanation, no beginners will understand, they can't rap there head around this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.